# unable to get message from gcm but its sends successfully in android

Tags: javascript, php, android, html

Am following google cloud messaging(gcm) example from androidhive. Through that I implemented in my application . I copied everything from that example but am unable to receive message from google cloud messaging(gcm),But it sends to gcm successfully. Am unable to call register class. Please explain me. and some times if I called receiver am unable to get message from server.Please solve it.

Comment: I found solution. I did silly mistake. I used different key to get intent message.

Comment: You should have debugged it before asking the question. Well Cheers that you solved your issue (y)